# Euler characteristic of an exhaustion of compacts of a surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ be an open (connected) Riemann surface of finite Euler characteristic.  And $K_1 \subset \cdots K_n \subset$ be an sequence of closures of bounded open subsets with smooth boundary of $X.$

Consider the sequence of Euler characteristic $\chi(K_n)$ of $K_n.$ Is there a known condition imposed on $\{K_n\}$ such that $\chi(K_n) \to \chi(X)?$

The example I'm having in mind is the case where $X$ is parabolic, then it admits a smooth positive exhaustion function $\sigma$ such that $\log \sigma$ is harmonic outside a fixed compact of $X$ and $K_t:= \{\sigma \le t\},$ $t \in R^+.$

It is said in a reference that in the case of the example, we have $\chi(K_n) \to \chi(X)$ but I couldn't explain it. Thank you.